# I hacked a bunch of peoples' bank accounts, what can I spend the money on?

Tags: watch-dogs

So I walked around doing a bunch of side quests for awhile to unlock different perks. While doing so I noticed a bunch of people had bank account info stored on their phones, so being the good opportunist I am, I hacked their phones and stole it and retrieved the money after making a stop at an atm. Now I have several hundred thousand dollars and don't know what to do with the money. I have already collected most of the weapons available, and I mainly only use my silenced pistol anyways, crafting parts don't really cost much and I am constantly refilling them anyways, and who needs to buy a car when everyone just leaves cars all around the city for you to use. Is there anything I can dump this money on such as upgrading stuff, other things to buy, or hiring people to do stuff for me?

TLDR: What can I spend all this money I stole on?

Comment: Ammunition,
    Crafting components from pawn shops,
    Items from Pharmingtons,
    Outfits,
    Sports drinks from cafes & bars or vending machines,
    Vehicles,
    Weapons ,

Answer (score 2):

You could spend money on poker, betting, cars, outfits, food/drink, guns, ammo, meds, crafting components or crafted items (jam com's, blackout, CtOS scans etc... only available at Tobias' shop).